# How to return images from asynctask on Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-asynctask, delegates

I am writing an application where I am building a list view in which each item has an image. The content of the list view is generated by an XML file that is stored locally, the pictures are fetched from Amazon AWS S3.

I want to write a class `AWSImageFetcher` that will be responsible for the authentication first (by using another dedicated class) and then for fetching the images.

I understood that it is best practice on Android to subclass `AsyncTask` in cases like this to perform the network requests. I am now wondering how I *should* return the images from the `AWSImageFetcher` class to the list view.

I am coming from iOS where I would just write a delegate for the `AWSImageFetcher` which would be invoked after the images have been fetched, but this doesn't feel right on Android. Should I use a listener class instead? How would you solve a situation like this on Android in an elegant way?

Comment: Could you show some (dummy) code to show *where* exactly you are stuck?

Comment: Why do you have to return a result? You can just use the onPostExecute() method and update/show your listview. Or is that not possible in your case?

Comment: i believe this was indeed the hint i needed, i was too stuck in thinking in iOS terms. using onPreExecute() for authentication and onPostExecute() for updating the list seems like a great way to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this form

onPreExecute executes first in UIThread, later doInbakground function execute in parellel thread then after that postExecute run in UIThread

```
private class AWSImageFetcher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 
{
    boolean authenticated;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        authenticated=authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        Bitmap b=null;
        if(authenticated)
        {
                URL imageUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT_IN_MILLI_SECONDS);
            conn.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT_IN_MILLI_SECONDS);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            b = decodeFile(f);
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result!=null)
        {               
            //use bitmap image in result    
        }
       else
       {   
          //Image is not available
       }    

    }

 }


//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i just came across one problem with the code. authentication involved a network request as well, so i can't do the authentication in onPreExecute(), right? anyway, the basic mechanism is clear to me, from here i will find a way myself! thanks!

Comment: k,thats good, you are welcome... then try authentication in doInBackground